# New / Edit Forms. Date Selection. Is it possible to limit the range of available dates

Tags: 2013, 2007

SharePoint 2007, with a pending upgrade to SharePoint 2013

Can anyone advise if its possible to limit the range of available dates within a SharePoint list?  my scenario is that I'm looking to build a self-booking system but want to be able to restrict dates available on each event.